# Provider side verification in Pact

Tags: python, pact, pactflow

Trying out pactflow with python. My consumer tests get published correctly, now for the verification side. Provider verification works as expected if I do this, with publish set to false:

```
# Define the provider and consumer names
PROVIDER_NAME = 'BackendService'
CONSUMER_NAME = 'FrontendApp'

# Create a new Verifier instance
verifier = Verifier(provider=PROVIDER_NAME, provider_base_url="http://127.0.0.1:8080")

# Configure the Verifier to use Pactflow as the broker
default_opts = {
    'pact_url': 'https://my_url.pactflow.io/pacts/provider/BackendService/consumer/FrontendApp/version/1.0.0',
    'broker_url': 'https://my_url.pactflow.io',
    'broker_token': 'my token',
    'publish_verification_results': False,
    'publish-version':'1.0.0',
    'provider_app_version': '1.0.0',
'consumer_app_version': '1.0.0'}
output, logs = verifier.verify_with_broker(**default_opts)
print(output)
```

When I try to set publish_verification_results to True, to see the results reflected in pactflow, I see:
`` venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pact/bin/pact/lib/vendor/ruby/3.2.0/gems/pact-1.63.0/lib/pact/provider/configuration/service_provider_dsl.rb:88:in `validate': Please set the app_version when publish_verification_results is true (Pact::Provider::Configuration::Error) ``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant to pass through `publish_version` (underscore)

See https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-python/blob/093d9b85c0c6bfc81be60e990e6c17ca103977fc/pact/verifier.py#L104C11-L104C11

Comment: Oh I didn't see that, works now thanks